# Hadoop Namenode and Secondary Namenode not starting with PDSH exit code 1

Tags: hadoop, ssh, namenode

```
aqib@aqib-Inspiron-5521:~$ start-dfs.sh
Starting namenodes on [aqib-Inspiron-5521]
pdsh@aqib-Inspiron-5521: aqib-Inspiron-5521: ssh exited with exit code 1
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [aqib-Inspiron-5521]
pdsh@aqib-Inspiron-5521: aqib-Inspiron-5521: ssh exited with exit code 1
```

Even after creating a localhost ssh with the below commands I am getting the same error:

```
ssh-keygen
ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id_rsa.pub localhost
```

Can anyone help me with this?